# Discover devices using bluetooth with xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Following the Android [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) I've created an app to connect a smartphone to a specific device using bluetooth.

However it has a problem, the scan for nearby devices doesn't detect all the devices every time. Sometimes it returns all the devices, sometimes it returns only a few. I'm running Android 6.0 and I've set all the permissions needed.

I see the same behavior with my phone bluetooth search (outside the application). This makes me wonder if the problem is in my code or is in fact a problem in android.

Has anyone had a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

If your code's able to discover through available devices then it's alright. I've used few times code from guide you've provided and everything was alright. Bluetooth time discovering could be important here. Maybe try to set something like TIMEOUTMILISEC for longer then it is. For example:

```
Intent discoverableIntent = new
Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
startActivity(discoverableIntent);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it doesn't solves my problem as I can't change the discovering bluetooth time in the devices being scanned and, as far as I've seen, I can't change the scanning time in android either.